# Maven ignoring Cucumber tag argument after a prior maven argument

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm

Currently I have the below maven command that consists of two different arguments, 1. testEnv (property set in my code), 2. cucumber tags.

I am not sure if my syntax is right for the cucumber tag options when it comes this cucumber version (4.8.1), but below is the command I am trying to run where it is ignoring/skipping the cucumber tags argument:

```
mvn clean test -DtestEnv=stg -Dcucumber.options="--tags @forecast"
```

Is there a reason why my program is running the first argument but not the cucumber tags argument?  When I execute the above command, it just runs everything regardless of the cucumber tag from the feature files.  Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of maven use the syntax

```
mvn clean test -DtestEnv=stg -Dcucumber.filter.tags="--tags @forecast"
```